# geom_dotplot displaying stacked on y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a dot plot of my data. The x-axis (discrete) is two different fluorophores (FAM & VIC), the y-axis is the CT value generated. However, when I graph this, all of my dots are stacked one atop the other, and don't appear to correlate to their actual CT value.

```
ggplot() +
 geom_dotplot(binaxis="x",stackdir="center",data=sub1,aes(x=Target.Name,y=CT))
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gQAR.png]

Comment: dotplots are stacked dots. Are you looking for lollipop plots instead? `geom_lollipop()` in the `ggalt` package will place your dots at their y values?

Comment: ``` r
#upload data
a1_1290summ <- read.csv("RSM0051290-001_summ.csv",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
a1_1290summ$CT <- as.numeric(a1_1290summ$CT)
a1_1290summ$Ct.Threshold <- as.numeric(a1_1290summ$Ct.Threshold)

#look at data
sub1 <- subset(a1_1290summ,!(is.na(CT)))

ggplot()+
  geom_dotplot(data=sub1,binaxis='x',stackdir='center',aes(x=Target.Name,y=CT
#> Error: <text>:19:0: unexpected end of input
#> 17: ggplot()+
#> 18:   geom_dotplot(data=sub1,binaxis='x',stackdir='center',aes(x=Target.Name,y=CT
#>    ^
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-14 by the [reprex package] </sup>